# Windows 10 UWP share files between different apps, same vendor

Tags: c#, uwp

Is there a way to share files between two different apps written by the same vendor on UWP Windows 10 Enterprise?  The apps Universal Windows apps written in C#.  I'd like to be able access files that are in the install package of App B from App A.

The basic problem I want to solve is to deploy config separately from the app using MDM.  I am thinking to have an App package and a Config package. Perhaps, there are better alternatives for deploying config separately using MDM.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the [publisher cache folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.storage.applicationdata.getpublishercachefolder.aspx),

Comment: And here's a [more elaborate post](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/24/sharing-your-local-app-data/#EGwrKmIQoOVAIbqz.97)